# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels'

Tags: python, python-module

I am getting the above error when trying to use the module statsmodels. I have installed the module through the command line and restarted spyder.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
```

I don't know if this is relevant but I am on Mac OSX which uses Python 2.7.16 as the default but I am using 3.9.5 in spyder.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you have multiple python versions you could be running the program with the wrong version. Can you double check that?

Comment: if you have many versions then you have to install it in correct version. If you run code with  `python3` then you can use `python3 -m pip install ...` to install module for `python2`. Every version need own installation.

Comment: @furas I ran this in my command line and it said already satisfied, I think I may have tried this earlier while trying to get this to work

Comment: Spyder may use different Python. Run in Spyder `import sys ; print(sys.executable)` to get full path to Python used in Spyder. And then you can use `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...`

Comment: @furas apologies for a late response on this, I am now getting the following error ```Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'```

Comment: it is different problem and you should ask new question on new page - you will have more space for code and description. But first check this problem in Stackoverflow or Google. I think I saw similar problems on Stackoverflow few times and you should find some solutions.